# How does genfromtxt work when you set delimiter to a sequence of integers?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning to import data with genfromtxt.I can't understand the example on numpy documentation.What is the use of each number in the sequence of integers and how does it work?(Maybe this is a stupid question...)

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

data = u"  1  2  3\n  4  5 67\n890123  4"
np.genfromtxt(StringIO(data), delimiter=3)

data = u"123456789\n   4  7 9\n   4567 9"
np.genfromtxt(StringIO(data), delimiter=(4, 3, 2))
```

Comment: This style of delimiter works if the text has consistent column widths but no delimiter character such as a comma or spaces.  Older FORTRAN code tended to write data like that.

Answer (score 1):

The [docstring for genfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) says this about the `delimiter` argument:

```
delimiter : str, int, or sequence, optional

    The string used to separate values. By default, any consecutive
    whitespaces act as delimiter. An integer or sequence of integers
    can also be provided as width(s) of each field.
```

The last sentence explains how an integer or sequence of integers are handled: the integers are interpreted as *field widths*.  In this case, there is no explicit delimiter character that separates the fields.  So in your second example,

```
data = u"123456789\n   4  7 9\n   4567 9"
np.genfromtxt(StringIO(data), delimiter=(4, 3, 2))
```

`delimiter` says "there are three fields; the first field is 4 characters long, the second is 3 characters and the third is two character".  The first line of text, `123456789`, is parsed as `1234`, `567`, `89`.

When `delimiter` is a *single* integer, it sets the field width of *all* the fields, and the number of fields is determined by the length of the line.  For example,

```
In [186]: np.genfromtxt(StringIO('123456'), delimiter=1, dtype=int)                                                             
Out[186]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

In [187]: np.genfromtxt(StringIO('123456'), delimiter=2, dtype=int)                                                             
Out[187]: array([12, 34, 56])

In [188]: np.genfromtxt(StringIO('123456'), delimiter=3, dtype=int)                                                             
Out[188]: array([123, 456])
```

Comment: Thank you!I can understand the mechanism better now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no use of this [this examples](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) numbers. They are just random numbers. The `\n` is the delimiter for each array. And every 3 chars (or numbers, which are also chars) a new value begins. So the given **delimiter** defines at how many chars the next value should begin.

So the result is:

```
array([[   1.,    2.,    3.],
       [   4.,    5.,   67.],
       [ 890.,  123.,    4.]])

array([[ 1234.,   567.,    89.],
       [    4.,     7.,     9.],
       [    4.,   567.,     9.]])
```

So don't focus on the numbers, they are just choosen randomly for the example.

Comment: So you mean that when the delimiter=(4,3,2) , in one dimension, firstly every 4 chars a new value begins, then every 3 chars, and lastly 2 chars?But it seems that in some lines, the number of chars is less than  9(ps:4+3+2=9)

Comment: (White-)spaces are chars too ;-)

Comment: Thank you for answering this question!